# strstr not returning desired result

Tags: c, strstr

Can you identify the error in this code, it's not being able to print the song even though I pass the valid parameters to find

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[]) 
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for)) {
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char askedSong[80];
    printf("%s", "Hey buddy, what is the good one today? ");
    fgets(askedSong, sizeof(askedSong), stdin);
    find_track(askedSong);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that fgets() regards a newline as a valid char and loads it into the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgets` leaves the newline in the string. Easy fix:

```
fgets(askedSong, sizeof(askedSong), stdin);
askedSong[strcspn(askedSong, "\n")] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Suppose you can get "\n" at the end after fgets. Need to trim it (if you are inputing from the keyboard). You can try to run using file input:
   yourexefile.exe < input.txt > output.txt
   and find that it works somehow
2. Suppose you should break after finding the result in the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `fgets` includes the trailing newline `'\n'` in `askedSong`.

Here's how I found it ---
I ran the program in a debugger and put a breakpoint in `find_track()`. Then when prompted I put in "girl" on the command line and saw that the argument to the function is "girl\n".

Here's what I see in the debugger:

```
Hey buddy, what is the good one today? girl

Breakpoint 1, find_track (search_for=0x7fffffffd9c0 "girl\n") at test.c:15
15      for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
(gdb)
```

There's a lot of wacky ways to trim that '\n' in C: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: Thanks dude, the recommendation helped me! I didn't know about this thing of fgets inserting a new line character at the end at all.

Answer (score 1):

probleme with fgets extra \n (enter)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[][80] = {
    "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
    "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
    "Dancing with a Dork",
    "From here to maternity",
    "The girl from Iwo Jima",
};

void find_track(char search_for[]) 
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for)!=NULL) {
            printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    char askedSong[80];
    printf("%s", "Hey buddy, what is the good one today? ");
    scanf("%s",askedSong);// try to use scanf to ovoid \n in the buffer
    find_track(askedSong);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that scanf doesn't allow spaced strings, and furthermore, it has problem dealing with size as well. In my case I think it's not the best option.

Comment: sorry for late response.but just for information you can allow spaced strings .and you can define the size of string example . ` scanf("%80[^\n]",askedSong);` .plz if you don't now it try it .it is very helpful .